# script para respaldar bases de datos mysql en php, pero requiero migrar a mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

```
    <?php

backup_tables('XXXXXXX','XXXXXXX','XXXXXXX','XXXXXXX');


/* backup the db OR just a table */
//En la variable $talbes puedes agregar las tablas especificas separadas por comas:
//profesor,estudiante,clase
//O déjalo con el asterisco '*' para que se respalde toda la base de datos

function backup_tables($host,$user,$pass,$name,$tables = '*')
{
   
   $link = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
   mysql_select_db($name,$link);
   
   //get all of the tables
   if($tables == '*')
   {
      $tables = array();
      $result = mysql_query('SHOW TABLES');
      while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
      {
         $tables[] = $row[0];
      }
   }
   else
   {
      $tables = is_array($tables) ? $tables : explode(',',$tables);
   }
   
   //cycle through
   foreach($tables as $table)
   {
      $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM '.$table);
      $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);
      
      $return.= 'DROP TABLE '.$table.';';
      $row2 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table));
      $return.= "\n\n".$row2[1].";\n\n";
      
    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++)
      {
         while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
         {
            $return.= 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES(';
            for($j=0; $j<$num_fields; $j++) 
            {
               $row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);
               $row[$j] = ereg_replace("\n","\\n",$row[$j]);
               if (isset($row[$j])) { $return.= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ; } else { $return.= '""'; }
               if ($j<($num_fields-1)) { $return.= ','; }
            }
            $return.= ");\n";
         }
      }
      $return.="\n\n\n";
   }
   
   //save file
   $handle = fopen('db-backup-'.time().'-'.(md5(implode(',',$tables))).'.sql','w+');
   fwrite($handle,$return);
   fclose($handle);
}

echo "<script>";
  echo "alert ('Respaldo realizado exitosamente.');";
  echo "window.location.replace('index.php');";
  echo "</script>";


?>
```

Funciona pero me marca estos errores:

> Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead.
>
> Deprecated: Function ereg_repace() is deprecated

He tratado de cambiar a `mysqli` pero deja de funcionar, podrían aconsejarme como puedo migrar a mysqli, también como podría restaurar la copia mas reciente respaldada.

Con respecto a que deja de funcionar, en realidad crea el archivo pero sin información y me marca los siguientes errores:

> Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string
> given in /backup/backup.php on line 15 Warning: mysqli_query() expects
> at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /backup/backup.php on line 21
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
> null given in /backup/backup.php on line 22

muchas gracias.

Comment: "deja de funcionar" no es una buena descripción del problema. ¿qué error ocurre? ¿alguna información del LOG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opción seria :

fíjate bien en la configuración del php por si esta activado la opción 'mysqli' en la parte de extensiones. Si no esta activado, no se puede usar.
Solo tienes que quitar el punto y coma al lado (;) y ya esta.

creo que es asi

```
...
;extensión = mysqli
...
```

Modificado:

En tal caso, yo diría que usted ha puesto mal el orden de los parámetros.

Según la documentación que se puede encontrar  [aqui](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php),

el objeto conector que es lo que obtengas al hacer la llamada

"mysqli_connect", debería venir como primer parámetro en la función "mysqli_select_db".

Por ejemplo, en el caso de "mysqli_select_db(Mysqli $link, String $nombre)",

$link(de tipo Mysqli) es el connector y $nombre(tipo String) es el nombre

de la base de datos al que intentas conecta.

Asi pues, debería usted revisar los demás que te han dado errores similares y

coregir según.

Espero que esto te sirve para resolver los errores.

Comment: Buen día, perdonen pero tuve problemas con el internet por eso contesto hasta ahora, con respecto a que deja de funcionar, en realidad crea el archivo pero sin información y me marca los siguientes errores:

Comment: Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in /backup/backup.php on line 15

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /backup/backup.php on line 21

Warning: mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /backup/backup.php on line 22

Comment: Con respecto a Mysqli todo el sistema que tengo creado funciona perfectamente y esta en mysqli, por eso no entiendo porque no puedo cambiar o quizas no es el formato correcto, ejemplo mysql_query  a  mysqli_query, si pueden ayudarme a migrarlo estaria de lujo porque ya busque de todas las formas posibles y nada, he buscado en internet pero no he logrado hacerlo funcionar correctamente con mysqli, muchas gracias por sus comentarios y su apoyo.

Comment: de hecho tendrias que revisar que version de PHP tienes, pues puede que ya no soporte mysql_connect() y tengas que actualizar el scriopt.  (Agrega un archivo con la sentencia `phpinfo();`para ver que version de PHP manejas)

Comment: Muchas gracias @P.J Palmer voy a checarlo como me comentas y te aviso que resultado obtuve, gracias.

Comment: Lo he modificado y ahora me marca este error:  Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object, le he investigado y cambiado cosas pero de ahi no lo he podido sacar.

Comment: Por cierto la version que maneja de php es la 5.5.35, al parecer si soporta mysql_connect()  pero la pongo de la siguiente manera mysqli_connect() y si funciona pero marca error en $mysqli->query de igual forma si lo pongo mysqli_query, de que forma puedo poner $mysqli->query sin que marque error?

Answer (score 0):

Ya he resuelto los errores que existían, cambie comandos obsoletos, ya no marca ningún error y respalda todas las tablas con su contenido, muchas gracias por sus comentarios, saludos.

Comment: Sería bueno saber cuáles fueron esos comandos obsoletos que cambiaste.